# Provsioning server error

Tags: java, apache-2.2

Hi I have a provsioning server which has started throwing some error: -

```
[29/May/2011:02:08:57] warning (19192) https-443.prams-prov.csfb.net: for host 111.53.93.220 trying to GET /home.cfm, send-file reports: HTTP4142: can't find /app/ws/prod/https-443.prams-prov.csfb.net/www-root/home.cfm (File not found)
[29/May/2011:02:08:57] warning (19192) https-443.prams-prov.csfb.net: for host 119.53.93.220 trying to GET /home.cfml, send-file reports: HTTP4142: can't find /app/ws/prod/https-443.prams-prov.csfb.net/www-root/home.cfml (File not found)
[29/May/2011:02:08:57] warning (19192) https-443.prams-prov.csfb.net: for host 119.53.93.220 trying to GET /default.cfm, send-file reports: HTTP4142: can't find /app/ws/prod/https-443.prams-prov.csfb.net/www-root/default.cfm (File not found)
[29/May/2011:02:08:58] warning (19192) https-443.prams-prov.csfb.net: for host 119.53.93.220 trying to GET /default.cfml, send-file reports: HTTP4142: can't find /app/ws/prod/https-443.prams-prov.csfb.net/www-root/default.cfml (File not found)
[29/May/2011:02:09:12] warning (19192) https-443.prams-prov.csfb.net: for host 199.53.93.220 trying to GET /webc.exe, send-file reports: HTTP4142: can't find /app/ws/prod/https-443.prams-prov.csfb.net/www-root/webc.exe (File not found)
[29/May/2011:02:09:12] warning (19192) https-443.prams-prov.csfb.net: for host 199.53.93.220 trying to POST /cgi-bin/cc_guestbook.pl, send-file reports: HTTP4142: can't find /app/ws/prod/https-443.prams-prov.csfb.net/www-root/cgi-bin/cc_guestbook.pl (File not found)
[29/May/2011:02:09:12] warning (19192) https-443.prams-prov.csfb.net: for host 199.53.93.220 trying to GET /start.php, send-file reports: HTTP4142: can't find /app/ws/prod/https-443.prams-prov.csfb.net/www-root/start.php (File not found)
[29/May/2011:02:09:12] warning (19192) https-443.prams-prov.csfb.net: for host 199.53.93.220 trying to GET /start.php, send-file reports: HTTP4142: can't find /app/ws/prod/https-443.prams-prov.csfb.net/www-root/start.php (File not found)
[29/May/2011:02:09:13] warning (19192) https-443.prams-prov.csfb.net: for host 199.53.93.220 trying to GET /superguestconfig, send-file reports: HTTP4142: can't find /app/ws/prod/https-443.prams-prov.csfb.net/www-root/superguestconfig (File not found)
```

Is this problem already familiar to anyone??

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an automated scanner blinding looking for vulnerable files on your web server; this is not an error with your device.